# Unity - Setting Script Execution Order inside a package

Tags: unity

When working inside of a Unity project, to set up the execution order for all the scripts is quite easy. It can be done under "Project settings". But when working developing a package, this option is not available, since we are not developing actively a Unity project.

But at the same time, I wish that every project that imports my package executes its scripts in the right order, without the user needing to set it up manually for every project.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example of the operations that need to run in a specific sequence? There might be other ways to sequence those operations, or remove their sequencing requirements.

Comment: For instance, I want to run the `Awake` method in a ScriptableObject before the `Awake` mehtod inside a MonoBehaviour that uses it.

Comment: Try showing us these scripts. We might be able to structure your package's code / API so that the necessary sequence is respected even if Awake is not called as desired. For instance, having the dependent object call an Initialize routine or a lazy initializing getter to trigger what's currently in your ScriptableObject's Awake.

Comment: I am already doing that. I just want to know if this is doable using the Script Execution Order system.